# How to get keys from values in dictionary and use it in dataframe?

Tags: python, list, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dataframe `df_x_encode`-

```
    x_test_encode
0   [0.1260023, -0.014597204, -0.079445906, -0.055...
1   [0.0083509395, 0.09799187, -0.05743032, -0.000...
2   [-0.05807189, 0.11802298, -0.031580053, -0.064...
3   [0.1260023, -0.014597204, -0.079445906, -0.055...
4   [0.121216424, -0.017603464, -0.090226464, -0.0...
```

I have a dict where the values from the column `x_test_encode` is the value and keys are text as follows -

```
{'Strengthening the field is a must ': array([ 1.75993890e-02,  7.26785734e-02, -7.36519024e-02, -2.17226259e-02,
         3.65523808e-02, -4.50823084e-03,  6.18522726e-02,  1.35725755e-02,
        -1.65322982e-02, -1.93105303e-02, -6.45413473e-02, -1.43367276e-02,
         3.43437083e-02, -5.04908897e-02, -7.43871846e-04, -2.44313944e-02,
         2.88490783e-02, -2.72445306e-02,  5.23326918e-02,  4.61216345e-02,
         2.41497066e-04, -8.29233676e-02, -9.53390170e-03, -7.67266843e-03,..],
.
.
.
```

I want to add a column `x_test` where the values will be taken from the dict keys.

Eg -

```
    x_test_encode                                        text
0   [0.1260023, -0.014597204, -0.079445906, -0.055...    This is to be noted that..
1   [0.0083509395, 0.09799187, -0.05743032, -0.000...    Strengthening the perfect..
2   [-0.05807189, 0.11802298, -0.031580053, -0.064...   
3   [0.1260023, -0.014597204, -0.079445906, -0.055...
4   [0.121216424, -0.017603464, -0.090226464, -0.0...
```

I am unable to get the keys from using the values and then map them to the rows of the dataframe.

Any help on this?

Comment: It's not clear if each array in the dict matches a dataframe row.
Can't find `0.1260023` in your example.

Comment: I want to add a new column in ```x_test_encode``` with the name ```x_test```.  For every row(where each value is a numpy array) in ```x_test_encode```, I want to search in all the values of the dictionary efficiently get the respective key of the same from the dictionary and add that key obtained (which will be a string)  in the respective row of the column ```x_test``` in the ```x_test_encode```.  @0x0fba

Answer (score 0):

- Make a new dictionary for use with [Series.map](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html)
  `f = {tuple(value):key for key,value in d}`
- Make a Series of tuples from the DataFrame column (of arrays)
  `s = df['a'].apply(tuple)`
- Map the dictionary to that Series and assign it to a new column
  `df = df.assign(new=s.map(f))`

---

Test data

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

rng = np.random.default_rng()
w = rng.integers(-10,10,(4,))
x = rng.integers(-10,10,(4,))
y = rng.integers(-10,10,(4,))
z = rng.integers(-10,10,(4,))

q = pd.Series({0:w,1:x,2:y,3:z,4:x+1})
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':q})

d = {'q':w,'r':x,'s':y,'t':z}
```

---

The new column will contain NaN for any row that doesn't *match* the dictionary.